# How to autocopy cell comment in a column when increasing rows on a dynamic table in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic table named *Tabla*, with two columns named *A* and *B*. I want every cells on those columns (new rows can be added with TAB key, increasing table size) to have the same comment.

[image]

In the screenshot that I've attached, you'll see the first row commented (with LIMIT text inside) but when I expand the dynamic table, the comment is not copied to the new rows of the table.

Comment: What code have you tried and where did you encounter the problem? Also, it seems you forgot to attach the screenshot.

Comment: @braX thanks, link to image added.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this not so need solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim oTbl As ListObject
  Set oTbl = Me.ListObjects("Tabla")

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  If Not oTbl.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, oTbl.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
      If tblRowCount <> oTbl.ListRows.Count Then
        tblRowCount = oTbl.ListRows.Count
        oTbl.DataBodyRange.Range("A1").Copy
        oTbl.DataBodyRange.Resize(, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteComments
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
      End If
    End If
    Target.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End If

End Sub
```

In a Module, you need to declare a public variable.

```
Public tblRowCount As Long
```

This detects increase in row through a public variable (global variable) and then copies the comment to the entire 1st column of the table. You can go play with it to adjust to your needs. Again, not so neat but will do what you want.

Comment: How to declare the public variable L42? Thanks.

Comment: @renguer0 You just need to add a `Module` then copy above declaration. Btw, the Private procedure goes to worksheet.

Comment: I tried but it don't work. The comments just don't copy to new dinamic table rows.